# How can i change the encoding of a php page?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, mb-convert-encoding

Im trying to change the encoding of a php file (through another php page) to UTF-8 , i mean without editor .

i tried to use **file_get_contents** and **file_put_contents** .

i used this code but it doesn't work !

```js
$text = file_get_contents('testencoding.php');
$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, "UTF-8");
file_put_contents('testencoding.php',$text);
```

this code above is working only if there is a "arabic" characters in the page.

Thanks,

Comment: And in other cases - what it does? Define `doesn't work`. And why don't you specify the `from_encoding` if you know it?

Comment: Im sorry im not good with english, I dont know the `from_encoding` because im making a website to convert the encoding from any encoding to UTF-8, i tried to use `mb_detect_encoding` but it returns `bool(false)` .. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You must specify `from_encoding` for the `mb_convert_encoding` function.

If `from_encoding` is not specified, [it'll use the internal encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).

Comment: what is the default `from_encoding` ? is it ansi ? or what ?

Comment: Default `from_encoding` is the internal encoding.

Comment: @Programmer4me - You can get the internal encoding by looking at `mb_internal_encoding()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$text = file_get_contents('testencoding.php');
file_put_contents('testencoding.php',utf8_encode($text));
```

if it doesn't work, try:

```
$text = file_get_contents('testencoding.php');
file_put_contents('testencoding.php',utf8_decode($text));
```

PS: consider marking the answer as correct if it works, tks :)